# How do I use the custom URL in a Swift app to open another Swift app

Tags: ios, swift3, deep-linking, custom-url

I have a custom URL set up for a Swift application. I would like to use this URL on another app's button action to deep link. I tried  `UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "redirectToApp://Testapp/startPage")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` but, it isn't working. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

`redirectToApp://Testapp/startPage` opens the app from a Safari.

Thanks!

Comment: *"it isn't working"* ... what does that mean? Do you get an error? Does some other app open? Does a web page open? Does *nothing* happen? Are you sure you are executing that line?

Comment: Action does nothing. No response at all.

Comment: this piece of code wasn't executing at all. all i got to do was, relaunch Xcode. may be because two projects were opened at the same time? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't use NSURL in Swift3, you should use the native Swift version, URL. On iOS9+ you also have to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entries to your Info.plist file in order to be able to open apps using deep links.

For example if you want to open the Uber app, you have to do: 
`UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "uber://)!).` from code and add these lines to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>uber</string>
</array>
```

Comment: this piece of code wasn't executing at all. all i got to do was, relaunch Xcode. may be because two projects were opened at the same time? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write code with error checking / handling so you can figure out what's not working.

Try it like this:

```
    if let url = URL(string: "redirectToApp://Testapp/startPage")
    {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                (success) in
                if (success)
                {
                    print("OPENED \(url): \(success)")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("FAILED to open \(url)")
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            print("CANNOT open \(url)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: this piece of code wasn't executing at all. all i got to do was, relaunch Xcode. may be because two projects were opened at the same time? Thank you for your time.